# Do multiple requests on a RCQ file

Tags: xml, api, rest, testing, rest-client

I'm trying to test a REST API using [Rest Client](http://code.google.com/p/rest-client/) and I'm wondering if it is possible to perform multiple request in a single rcq file.

Documentation is outdated :(

If it is not possible, do you know some good testing frameworks or tools to test a REST API?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't figured out, so I finally decided to use [Jmeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/) by Apache, it's well documented (in contrast to Rest Client) and I could find lot of example over the internet.

It's a little rough at first, but eventually I managed to build my test on it.

I recommend it.